# ReSharper Unit Test Runner: Support for Deployment Items

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

I like the Unit test runner in ReSharper 4.5, and would like to use it with my MSTest tests, but one thing annoys me:

In some of our solutions, we have set up some Deployment Items in the  .testrunconfig file. The ReSharper Unit Test runner does not seem to respect this, so I get errors when trying to run the unit tests from ReSharper.

Is there any workraound for this ?

**Update:**

*citizenmatt*'s answer was correct, the option to use a .testrunconfig with ReSharper exists in the Options dialog of ReSharper. You have to select the unit test provider on the list, then the controls to do that appears. (That was not obvious or discoverable, at least not for me ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you had a look in the Unit Testing options page? There's a setting there to allow you to use a specified test run configuration, or a test run configuration specified in a metadata file. I'm not sure what it means - I've never used it - but it sounds like it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Post-Build event of your test project? Put all your deployable items in a .BAT (.cmd) file and call it in Post-Build event to get everything deployed.

Comment: I was kinda trying to avoid that - but I might have to fall back on that, if I do not find a way to make deployments work.