# Mobile Emulator Launched for non-mobile unit tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, compact-framework, mstest, emulation

I have a Compact Framework Project that has two Unit Test projects with it in the solution.

One is a Smart Device Unit Test Project (needs the emulator to run).  The other is a normal Unit Test Project.

The normal Unit Test Project runs fine on my machine and on the build machine, but on my co-worker's machine it tries to launch the emulator then fails the tests.

He has tried doing a checkout of changeset 1 then deleting the folder then checking out and running the test but it still tries to launch the emulator.

Because both the build machine and my computer work just fine, I am guessing that this is some setting that he may have on his machine.

Any ideas?

(using visual studio 2008 and mstest)

Comment: you've checked the testrunconfig?

Comment: @ctacke: That was it!  Resharper was not using the correct testrunconfig.  (As seen in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747263/resharper-unit-test-runner-support-for-deployment-items).  Post this as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the testrunconfig.  We were running from resharper and it was not selecting the correct testrunconfig.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the solution's debug settings. If you right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select *Properties*, there's a node called *Startup Project*. The settings in this dialog are kept in the solution's .suo file, which is normally not checked in to source control.

It may be this or one of the other nodes in this Solution Properties dialog that defines the difference.