# ReSharper Unit Test Runner ignores deployment items configuration

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, resharper-6.1

I'm using Resharper 6.1 for unit testing a new project and it seems to ignore the the Deployment section of my local.testsettings file.

I tried to configure in "ReSharper -> Options -> Unit testing -> MSTest -> Use this test run configuration" to explicitly use the local.testsettings file, how is suggested in this question: [ReSharper Unit Test Runner: Support for Deployment Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747263/resharper-unit-test-runner-support-for-deployment-items), but nothing happens.

Desperately I tried to move the files out of the test project, create another Test Settings file, move the test project to another solution, but still nothing.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-295311) should be fixed in ReSharper 7 here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html.

Thank you!

Comment: But I don't really want to buy the new version 7. It would be better if it was working better in version 6.1, we buy the version 6.1 just eight months ago. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Nope it is not fixed. I just have the same issue with Resharper 7.1.3 and Visual Studio 2012. The items listed in the testsettings file will not be deployed at all.

Answer (score 6):

This is also a ReSharper-Configuration problem that I encounter myself. May this help you.

When I try to run the application, it get this ReSharper error: "The project to be run with this configuration is not present in the solution"

[image]

In Resharper help page, I found the path to the run configurations:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Run_Configurations.html

**ReSharper | Tools | Run Configurations...**
[image]

Since the project doesn't exist anymore, I delete that connfiguration:

**{Project Name} > Configure > Delete...**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same ReSharper error in VS2019, VS2022:

> ReSharper – Failed to execute run configuration
>
> The project to be run with this configuration is not present in the
> solution.

Turns out that you don’t have to necessarily run the project that is problematic. If there is some configuration saved for another project in ReSharper, and that project is not present anymore (for example, you’ve switched branches or deleted some project from the solution), this error will pop-up. It was my case.

Solution is as described above:

Go to **Extensions -> ReSharper -> Tools -> Run configurations… -> nonExistingProject -> Configure -> Delete**

This will delete configuration that is preventing ReSharper to work well and blocks your run at the IDE.

Apparently, still not fixed...