# ReSharper Line Breaks and Wrapping

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

So, this:

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand( string.Format( @"
SELECT *
  FROM Bobby_Tables
 WHERE Name = {0}", "Little Bobby Drop Tables" ), odbcConnection );
```

gets formatted to:

```
cmd = 
      new OdbcCommand( 
            string.Format( 
                  @"
SELECT *
  FROM Bobby_Tables
 WHERE Name = {0}", 
                  "Little Bobby Drop Tables" ), odbcConnection );
```

I've looked at each of the options for line breaks and wrapping but I haven't been able to find the one to keep things on the same line as long as possible.  I'm assuming that I missed the correct option.  My `Right margin (columns)` option is set to 100, which is plenty big.

**Question:**  Is there a way to make it look like the original, and still get smart formatting on other things that actually do need to be wrapped?

I can manually put the

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand( string.Format (
      @"
```

back on the first line and it'll leave the verbatim string on the next line happily.  That's an alright compromise I guess.

Comment: Try setting the "Keep existing line breaks" property to true under Code Editing => C# => Formatting Style => Line Breaks and Wrapping.  You can also shortten the "Right margin (columns)" property so that the right margin is smaller and thus "Chop if long" doesn't happen as often.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Do you want Resharper to bring the Select statement all back into a single line? If so, I don't think it will do that. Resharper is usually trying to reformat code and break it up for readability.

Comment: Love the xkcd reference. "maybe you will learn to sanitize your sql".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Resharper from line breaking after return keyword for long lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509768/how-to-stop-resharper-from-line-breaking-after-return-keyword-for-long-lines)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I guess that your problem is that the first line got broken in three. This is because of bug http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288271 that was fixed in ReSharper 7.0. You should consider upgrading or turning off option `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting style | Line breaks and wrapping -> LineWrapping | Wrap long lines`.

Comment: Hey @Dmitry Osinovskiy, maybe you have a clue about a problem I'm having with ReSharper 6.1? If you could, please take a look in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622581/resharper-unit-test-runner-ignores-deployment-items-configuration

Comment: We're still on 6.1.  I'm using a Right Margin of 100, so it should be plenty.

It seems like, "Oh, this new OdbcCommand() is too long, put it on a new line.  Oh, this string.Format() is too long, put it on a new line.  Oh, this verbatim string is too long, put it on a new line."

At least, that's how I imagine the algorithm working.

Comment: @devundef Unfortunately I don't have a clue. But you can always try to ask him https://twitter.com/fergard/status/228271877393633280

Comment: As a new user to ReSharper, I'm surprised at how many defaults it has that I disagree with!  This was one.  Thanks for pointing out how to turn it off.

Comment: @Mmm Select solution in Solution Explorer, Extensions > ReSharper > Edit > Detect formatting settings to find all of them at once

Comment: The option to turn off the wrapping of long lines is now located at ```Extensions > ReSharper> Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Editing > General > Wrap long lines```. Simply un-check the check-box, if it is selected.