# Why is ReSharper providing strange formatting with string interpolation?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

ReSharper's formatting keeps placing string interpolations on different lines, such as:

```
$" whatever = {somethingelse}"
```

becomes:

```
$" whatever={
         somethingelse
      }"
```

Any idea which option this is?

Comment: This has got to be a bug, no way should it format a string like it's code even if it kinda is now.

Comment: @juharr Yeah, looks like that to me too. Maybe related to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-434676) or [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-447081).

Comment: What version of Resharper are you using?  I think only 9 is suppose to work with 2015 and the new C# 6 stuff.

Comment: Latest. Just checked for updates this morning and im up to date. Quick googling didn't find the issue so I assumed it wasn't a bug.

Comment: Didn't do that when I removed it a month ago (still a CPU hog). Must be a new bug

Comment: I am using ReSharper 9.2 and it formats the code correctly.

Comment: Using ReSharper 10 and this still happens. http://i.imgur.com/zyF1gyc.png

Comment: Did you try exporting your ReSharper settings and resetting ReSharper's configuration?

Comment: Seams to work with Resharper latest version : 2016.1.1 on VS 2015. I do not use old versions of Resharper. Does old versions 9.2 or 10 have updates supporting C# 6 string interpolation ?

Comment: Updated to latest and seems to be working. However, it's been a while and I've changed settings since then so not sure if I had inadvertently(?) fixed it anyway.

Comment: Works for simple things like that. It seems to be failing on long sql queries. Like so: http://i.imgur.com/bbdymes.png becomes http://i.imgur.com/MHjbesb.png

Comment: I believe your issue is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11746111/5038208

Answer (score 1):

"Wrap object and collection initializer" is the setting you're after. Set it to chop if long and then if it's still wrapping incorrectly you can modify the "Right Margin (columns)" number to a much larger value and it will stop the behavior. Though by expanding the columns resharper will stop wrapping anything with fewer characters on the line than the value you set so it may make other reformatting perform in an undesirable way.

[image: Resharper object initializer options]

[image: Resharper Column Options]