# ReSharper run unit test but have wrong location and missing configuration file (ApplicationBase)

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper

When I run unit test from `ReSharper` my `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation` have path: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\hwa3yebt.mas\<project>.config` (IIS temp dictionary)
and it doesn't work and throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` becouse can not find configuration file.

Configuration file has Copy to output directory : Copy always (I'm not sure if this is required)

but when I run unit test from Visual Studio test explorer `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation` have path : `C:/Repository/<project>/bin/debug` and it works.

What I should do to run `ReSharper` unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

Check 
[Resharper runs UnitTest from different location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231084/resharper-runs-unittest-from-different-location)

Answer (score 0):

This could be because Reshaper has shadow copy turned on by default. This means that the test will run from a different location then projects default output path. You can turn this off by removing this default.

ReSharper > Options... > Tools > Unit Testing > Shadow-copy assemblies being tested

Comment: Having the same problem, that option didn't really fix it.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile points to 
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\n0mthe3j.lik\[guid].config